# Append File Name in each record of imported CSV into excel

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have written following macro which imports all the CSV files from a directory in which the Active Excel Spreadsheet resides. Now I would like to append corresponding file names of the CSVs in last column of each record but I am not able to figure out how to do this. Could anyone give me a pointer.

```
Sub ImportAllCSV()
  Dim FName As Variant, R As Long
  R = 1
  FName = Dir("*.csv")
  Dim counter As Integer, startRow As Integer
  counter = 0
  Do While FName <> ""
    If counter = 0 Then
      startRow = 3
    Else
      startRow = 4
    End If
    load_csv FName, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Cells(R, 1), startRow
    R = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    FName = Dir
    counter = counter + 1
  Loop

End Sub

Sub load_csv(fStr As Variant, Position As Range, startRow As Integer)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fStr, Destination:=Position)
        .Name = "CAPTURE"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = startRow
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With your `load_csv` Function you merely import your csv, but you could do much more (for example writing the file name wherever)... Consider also that when you import, you have to say **which file** you have to pick. That leads to a simple thought: the file name should be already there somewhere in your Function!

Hint: `fStr`

I would also suggest to mantain only the commands you need on the import... Those seems recorded with the Excel Macro-Recorder and some of them might not be of any help.